# Angular input field refresh issue after http get call

Tags: angular

I am rendering data from http get response, trying to map it with input field but its not assigning.

```js
this.http.get<any>('https://localhost:9002/....../getEmail')
      .subscribe({
          next: data => {
          this.emailAddress = data.emailAddress;
          
          },
          error: error => {
            
          }
      });
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailAddress" [(ngModel)]="emailAddress" />
```

input field value is not updating, when we are trying to update through http get.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

subscribe takes three callback methods as parameter one for response, second for handling error and third for completion
but you are passing object

```
  this.http.get<any>('https://localhost:9002/....../getEmail')
  .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.emailAddress = res.emailAddress;
      },
      error => {
        // handle error
      }
  );
```